# Связь формы с другого сайта

Tags: python, поиск, форма

Есть сайт А с формой в которую вводишь текст нажимаешь найти и по сайту происходит поиск. Пример: Ситилинк и его поиск. Можно ли этот поиск использовать на стороннем ресурсе или в Python (Можно и другой язык) или другом приложении, для получения ссылки (Для своих нужд)? Пример: Я ввожу Iphone X на своем сайте/приложении и он ищет используя форму с другого сайта ссылку на IphoneX с Ситилинка. Или это нельзя сделать? Если можно, есть ли какой либо пример?

Comment: 1) Вы хотите использовать чужой поиск у себя? - нет так не выйдет, если владелец поисковой системы не даст на это добро(а вместе с добром и исходник)
2) Вы хотите сделать свой поисковик по другим сайтам - так можно(но это тема отдельной книги).

Comment: Смотря как реализован поиск. Попробуйте через Fiddler посмотреть, какие запросы отправляются на сайт. Если это простые get/post запросы, то, возможно, вы сможете эмулировать обращения к сайту просто через Python. А если там что-то хитрое на JavaScript и т.д., то тоже можно попробовать через Silenium webdriver эмулировать открытие страницы, ввод данных и получение результата.